# Is it not possible to nest _.each statements in underscore.js templates?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This is my template. Pretty simple but for some reason the _.each statements are being outputted above my table.

```
    <script type="text/template" id="SearchResultsTmp">
        <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
        <%_.each(m.data, function(o){ %>
            <tr>
            <span class="ResultValueHeader"><b><%= o[m.settings.FieldName] %></b></span>
            <br/>
            <%_.each(m.settings.ResultFields, function(rf){ %>
            <span class="ResultField"><%= rf.Alias %>:</span>
            <p class="cs_ResultFieldValue"><%= o[rf.FieldName] %></p>
            <br/>
            <% }) %>
            </tr>
        <% }) %>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/UFn37/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be the direct consequence of not using any td inside your tr to wrap your contents.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to output? See http://jsfiddle.net/GspJx/

The problem is with the HTML markup you used for the table. You need to have proper `<tr>` and `<td>` tags for your `<table>`.